# Get root category name for ASIN from MWS API

Tags: amazon-mws

I'm trying to calculate the FBA fees in a Nodejs application. I get the product group and the product type name from the advertising API but I need the root category name for given products. How can I do that?

Edit1: additionally I'd also like to be able to check whether a specific product is media or apparel

Comment: Have you found any solution to that? I'm stuck with the same. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50657366/get-the-product-category-with-amazon-product-advertising-api

Comment: You can try `GetMyFeesEstimate` MWS API to get fee details. http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/products/Products_GetMyFeesEstimate.html

Answer (score 2):

The [Products API](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/products/Products_GetProductCategoriesForASIN.html) should be what you're looking for.  Specifically, the `GetProductCategoriesForASIN` operation.  You can make a request for up to 20 ASINs at a time.  The `GetMatchingProductForId` operation might also work, that has the product rankings within each category.

The client libraries are [here](https://developer.amazonservices.com/gp/mws/api.html/190-9453901-7569555?ie=UTF8&group=products&section=products&version=latest), just plug in your credentials and see if this works for you.

Comment: I should've mentioned that I've tried all the obvious ways. The routes that you mentioned, while they do give product category, they don't give the ROOT product category on whose basis the referral fees and variable fees are calculated