# Get the product category with Amazon Product Advertising API

Tags: amazon-product-api

With the `Amazon Product Advertising API`, I am able to retrieve the products list with `ISBN`, `ASIN`, and `UPC`. I have all the information like **Title**, **Image**, **Best Sellers Rank** etc. Now I want to retrieve the product category. In the response, I'm getting the following Product attributes

```
<ItemAttributes>
            <Binding>Office Product</Binding>
            <Brand>3M</Brand>
            <CatalogNumberList>
                <CatalogNumberListElement>MMMTP5851100</CatalogNumberListElement>
            </CatalogNumberList>
            <Color>NA</Color>
            <EAN>0778853213952</EAN>
            <EANList>
                <EANListElement>0778853213952</EANListElement>
                <EANListElement>0823019692079</EANListElement>
                <EANListElement>0800011321299</EANListElement>
                <EANListElement>0804993541201</EANListElement>
                <EANListElement>0801593278209</EANListElement>
                <EANListElement>0051141366623</EANListElement>
                <EANListElement>0809302061470</EANListElement>
                <EANListElement>0638084746578</EANListElement>
                <EANListElement>0739197517144</EANListElement>
            </EANList>
            <Feature>Tough, moisture resistant polyester film.</Feature>
            <Feature>Preserve and protect keepsake photos and documents.</Feature>
            <Feature>Keep frequently used documents neat and legible.</Feature>
            <ItemDimensions>
                <Height Units="hundredths-inches">438</Height>
                <Length Units="hundredths-inches">263</Length>
                <Weight Units="Hundredths Pounds">41</Weight>
                <Width Units="hundredths-inches">125</Width>
            </ItemDimensions>
            <Label>3M Office Products</Label>
            <ListPrice>
                <Amount>1012</Amount>
                <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
                <FormattedPrice>$10.12</FormattedPrice>
            </ListPrice>
            <Manufacturer>3M Office Products</Manufacturer>
            <Model>TP5851100</Model>
            <MPN>TP5851-100</MPN>
            <NumberOfItems>1</NumberOfItems>
            <PackageDimensions>
                <Height Units="hundredths-inches">120</Height>
                <Length Units="hundredths-inches">520</Length>
                <Weight Units="Hundredths Pounds">10</Weight>
                <Width Units="hundredths-inches">270</Width>
            </PackageDimensions>
            <PackageQuantity>1</PackageQuantity>
            <PartNumber>TP5851-100</PartNumber>
            <ProductGroup>Office Product</ProductGroup>
            <ProductTypeName>OFFICE_PRODUCTS</ProductTypeName>
            <PublicationDate>2014-03-14</PublicationDate>
            <Publisher>3M Office Products</Publisher>
            <Size>100-Pouches</Size>
            <Studio>3M Office Products</Studio>
            <Title>Scotch Thermal Laminating Pouches, 2.32 x 3.70-Inches, Business Card Size, 100-Pack (TP5851-100)</Title>
            <UPC>638084746578</UPC>
            <UPCList>
                <UPCListElement>638084746578</UPCListElement>
                <UPCListElement>739197517144</UPCListElement>
                <UPCListElement>801593278209</UPCListElement>
                <UPCListElement>051141366623</UPCListElement>
                <UPCListElement>778853213952</UPCListElement>
                <UPCListElement>800011321299</UPCListElement>
                <UPCListElement>809302061470</UPCListElement>
                <UPCListElement>804993541201</UPCListElement>
                <UPCListElement>823019692079</UPCListElement>
            </UPCList>
        </ItemAttributes>
```

I want the exact category of the product because I want to calculate the `Amazon Referral Fee` and `Variable Closing Fee` based on the information at https://sellercentral.amazon.com/gp/help/external/200336920?language=en_US&ref=efph_200336920_cont_19211

and for that, I need the exact category. Based on each category Seller has to pay a percentage of the price to Amazon as Amazon referral fee. So is there any way that I can retrieve the exact category?

**Edit**: I have tried with browse nodes in response. It gives me the category nodes. There is also an `isRootCategory` response value which tells either the category is root or not.
e.g for a cloth item it gives me root category of `Clothing, Shoes and Jewellary`. But to calculate the refferal fee, that product must have a root category of 'Clothing & Accessories'. So that refferal fee of `17%` can be calculated based on the item price.

Comment: Just add browse nodes to your desired response

Comment: @baao check the edit.

Comment: That's all information you will get from that API (and you can still use that). However, I'd recommend using amazon MWS for that - there's even a call that will return the fees directly (at least for FBA). See http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/products/Products_GetProductCategoriesForSKU.html

Comment: And the different report types available http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/reports/Reports_ReportType.html

Comment: @baao I will try that and thank you for the help.

Comment: @baao to get the Fees estimates, I need to know the parameters like Item Price, shipping price, Is Amazon Fulfilled. Do `Product Advertising API` provide all that.

Comment: No, how should it? The product advertising API is targeted towards people who want to create ads, you can't get your price from that. You can use the GetMyPriceForSku Operation (again mws) for that information.

Comment: Ok. And what is the difference between `Get Competitive pricing`, `Get Lowest offer listing`, and `Get Lowest price offers`. Basically I need to get the Fba price, buy box price and merchant fulfilled price. And I also want to calculate the FBA fees. So which request I should use.

Comment: Amazon's documentation (and the example responses) explain the differences in detail, far better than I could. Do you want that for your own products? Then you need (like already mentioned) the GetMyPriceForSku / GetMyPriceForAsin Operation to get the prices. For FBA Fees I would just download the report. I already posted a link to the report types. Just search for FBA Fee Preview Report there. Which marketplace are you targeting? US?

Comment: I'm targeting US marketplace but it's not for my own products. I want it for all users.

Comment: Hm. I don't understand then what you are trying to do

Comment: I want to create an application where user can search the products and compare the gross proceeds etc.

Comment: Yeah I thought that's what you are doing. You'll have to let your users register your app with amazon. After that, you can use the operations for MyPrice and download the respective sellers reports for the fees. Anything other than that will make your app fail as there are quite strict throtteling policies in place. The request quota is calculated by seller->app combination... If you try to do this with a single seller account you'll run into request is throttled errors alll the time

Comment: That's why I'm using product advertising API to get the data based on ASIN, UPC etc. But I stuck with the FBA fees calculations. Because to calculate the referral fee, I need to know the root category.

Comment: I don’t think it will be possible with that api. You only get the buy box price from there, not a single user’s price. I’ve tried it that way too, forget it...

Comment: No it provides you the lowest prices. But without shipping charges.

Comment: Let them register, then download a single inventory report price and quantity, that’s all you need

Comment: Ah no not even that... it’s the list price. That’s the usually strikes through one (sometimes matches though)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will get back to you, if I further need your assistance. I will try your suggestion and really appreciate your help.